# Packet sniffer socket exception

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, sniffer

On the following code

```
        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
        s.Bind(new System.Net.IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),0));
        s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
        byte[] bin = new byte[4]{1, 0, 0, 0};
        byte[] bout = new byte[4];
        s.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, bin, bout);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Socket Exception: An invalid argument was supplied
```

On the following line

```
        s.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, in, out);
```

But I dont understand why I've supplied a wrong argument.

Comment: The line you claim the error occurs on does not exist in the provided code. I suppose a mod was required to make it work because `out` is reserved. Please update your question.

Comment: Does it compile with a variable name `out`? If so I'm surprised, because it's a reserved keyword. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: changed the vars and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I've found it.

127.0.0.1 is not a proper IP adress annotation for this. I have to use my local one (192.168.0.100);

Darn, it's always so easy.

Answer (score 1):

See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a3744sh.aspx) and the [IOControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.iocontrolcode.aspx) doc, specifically for .ReceiveAll:

> Enable receiving all IPv4 packets on
>   the network. The socket must have
>   address family InterNetwork, the
>   socket type must be Raw, and the
>   protocol type must be IP. The current
>   user must belong to the Administrators
>   group on the local computer, and the
>   socket must be bound to a specific
>   port. This control code is supported
>   on Windows 2000 and later operating
>   systems. This value is equal to the
>   Winsock 2 SIO_RCVALL constant.Winsock 2 SIO_RCVALL constant.

Is it possible you aren't in the Administrators group, or you bound to an incorrect port? It seems like you set the other options correctly.  Although, having said all that, your code looks identical to [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CSNetworkSniffer.aspx) so it should work?  Can you dig further into the exception to read possibly more detailed inner exceptions?

Comment: Heya, I'm pretty sure I'm in an adminsitrator's group. I even added the following manifest:
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"/> 
And there are no further inner exceptions. And I'm also runnning VS in administrator