# Error in IOControlCode.ReceiveAll Method

Tags: c#, sockets

I am making application in C#. I have code as follows and I am running application as ADMINISTRATOR. I am using windows 7.
Code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 24097)); 
            socket.ReceiveBufferSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; 
            socket.ReceiveTimeout = 500; 
            byte[] invalue = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
            byte[] outvalue = new byte[4];
            int c = socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, invalue, outvalue);
```

> Error: An invalid argument was supplied.

Comment: Why the downvote? Downvoter can you tell me the reason?

Comment: This down-vote is propably because you're asking wrong ,you just typed Code not a Description with you're problem.No-one will read code to understand you're problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Packet sniffer socket exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013217/packet-sniffer-socket-exception)

Comment: @Cody: The title in combination with `Error: An invalid argument was supplied` describes the problem.

Comment: @Cody : i am getting error as " An invalid argument was supplied." What type of description u want ?

Comment: @Dany: Check the link that I provided in a comment.

Comment: An invalid argument was supplied to *what* ? There is no indication of the error exact location here.

Comment: @alex : i mentioned in the name of question that error in method socket.IOControl()

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use IPAddress.Any, that will generate the Invalid argument. Try IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1") instead.